# Updating collection in many side of a one to many releationship

Tags: entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

I am modeling the following many-to-many relationship using Domain Driven Design (DDD).

[image: Many-to-Many relationship in DDD]

I am using EF Core for persistence.

The collection on Person is configured like this:

**PersonConfigurations.cs**

```
builder.OwnsMany(o => o.PersonOrgIds, ib =>
{
    ib.ToTable("PersonPersonOrgIds");
    ib.WithOwner()
        .HasForeignKey("PersonId");
    ib.HasKey("Id");
    ib.Property(id => id.Value)
        .HasColumnName("PersonOrgId");
});

builder.Metadata.FindNavigation(nameof(Person.PersonOrgIds))!
    .SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
```

Then PersonOrg models the relationship like this:

**PersonOrgConfigurations.cs**

```
builder.Property(o => o.PersonId).IsRequired()
    .HasConversion(
        id => id.Value,
        value => PersonId.Create(value));
```

My question is when I add a PersonOrg how can I reflect that in the collection of Person (and Org).

Comment: Don't mix persistence concerns with your domain logic. Design your models after the business processes, then look for persistence. If you try to model your domain after the persistence, you already lost the battle.

Comment: Your question doesn't inform us about the aggregate design. Who is the root? What are the aggregates? What are the invariants?